# What happens when SPF includes domain that does not have SPF but A record instead

Tags: domain-name-system, email, spf

A company whose mail servers we occasionally use to send emails has asked us to include their domain in our SPF record as follows: `v=spf1 [...] include:app.sgizmo.eu ~all`.

Now it turns out that there is actually no SPF record on the domain we're pointing to `app.sgizmo.eu`. The only records there are `A` records that change all the time (probably cloudflare).

From all I know about SPF, the absence of SPF records on the `app.sgizmo.eu` means that our `include` has absolutely no impact. It's as if it wasn't there.

What confuses me is that the SPF check tool [spf-record.com](https://www.spf-record.com/spf-lookup?domain=fieldworkhub.com) lists the IPs that appear in the `app.sgizmo.eu` `A` record as `allowed` for email sending with the following wording:

> Additional, external SPF records.
>
> We could find other records authorized in the SPF record: app.sgizmo.eu
>
> A records: 52.222.174.243
>   52.222.174.77
>   52.222.174.112
>   52.222.174.23

Is that a bug of the tool? Or is my understanding of SPF wrong and lack of SPF record means that A records count as accepted IPs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're understanding is correct and this seems to be a bug in the tool. Or perhaps it is common practice to deviate from the RFC for SPF and allow this behaviour.

If you use the [Dmarcian tool](https://dmarcian.com/spf-survey/), it will fail, as it should following the SPF RFC.
The [RFC states](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7208#section-5.2) the include mechanism should reference a valid SPF (`TXT`) record. In case none is found, it should return a PERMERROR.

For this to work, you may add `a:app.sgizmo.eu`, if these are indeed the IP addresses used to send out emails on your behalf.

Comment: Thank you so much, that's splendid feedback!